# Generalization of $(HK:H)=(K:K \cap H)$?

Tags: group-theory

Suppose we are given subgroups $H,K$ of a finite group $G$. Denote by $\langle H,K\rangle$ the subgroup generated by $H,K$.

If $H$ is normal in $G$, then $\langle H,K\rangle = HK$ and 
$$(\langle H,K\rangle:H) = (K:H \cap K)\tag{$\ast$}$$

Is there a generalization of $(\ast)$ if $H$ is not necessarily normal ?

Comment: (*) is false, try two cyclic subgroups of $S_3$ of order $2$.

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked for a generalization, maybe using some conjungates.

Comment: The LHS is always greater than or equal to the RHS.